# Serialized my in App "Shopping Cart" now trying to send it to a server using http Post - doesn't reach destination

Tags: iphone, http, serialization, post

I have a shopping cart in my app and an underlying data structure that I have serialized into an XML file. Im using the following code to place it on my server. However, nothing happens. Whe I check my server I donot find my file there. So I tried using just a string in place of the file and still the same. Nothing seems to be sent from the app to the server. Im running ths off the simulator.

Im wondering if there is anything wrong with this code.

```
CartSingleton *Cart = [CartSingleton getSingleton];

 id xmlFile = [Cart serializeCart];

 //Now send the xml file to the server

 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.XXXXXXXXX.com/iOS_Files/xmlFile"];

 NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

 [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

 NSData *paramData = [xmlFile dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 [req setHTTPBody:paramData];

 NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];


 if(theConnection)

    {

      NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

      self.receivedData = data;

      [data release];

    }

 else 

    {

      NSLog(@"Unable to make connection!");

    }
```

I would really appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some information on what you have running on the server to receive this? Do you have any other means to check what the server receives? How about server logs to see if a connection is even being made?

Comment: No, I donot have anything setup on the server currently. I just want to ensure the file is saved on the server. I donot see the file or the string on the server. My server space is a URL on goDaddy.

Comment: see my updated answer, now it has the link to the iOs class reference, usage guide, there's also a hint of how you can check your server behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible problem with the above code (their may be others also), is that the connection setup will be asynchronous. This is why you had to supply a delegate object above. Therefore, the connection is not actually made until the delegate gets a callback to say it is ready.

Have you implemented any delegate methods?

Comment: no im new to this and I looked at many websites for sample code and generated this code based on those examples that I saw.
I couldn't find a single site that had code for what I intend to do. It seems that this is a common procedure and it would be easy to look for sample code. However, maybe Im searching using the wrong keywords. Could anyone recommend some sites or key words that I should use to search for sample code that does this.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See the class [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLConnection), there you can also find the links for the sample applications.

That code

```
    if(theConnection)

{

  NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

  self.receivedData = data;

  [data release];

}
```

does not start the connection. The receivedData property will have a new NSData object, which is then changed as the response data received.

For the better understanding of the NSUrlConnection usage follow that official [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

What you can do else is to test the server w/o the application using REST Client firefox extension (just send the post request with it and see what happens).